# Java Swing ItemListener for CheckBox not responding to state change

Tags: java, swing, null

What I am after is I would like for whenever someone checks a checkbox, the text for which the box they selected is output to the right panel(I have a split pane). Right now it is not responding so I don't think my BoxHandler is working properly(implements ItemListener). My function addBoxListeners is supposed to add item listeners for each checkbox that I have and the function I overrode in BoxHandler, function itemStateChanged should add text to the right panel, and I know that addText is working because I tested it outside of the itemListener stuff.

```
  void addText(String s) { // adds text to the right panel, adds string s
      JLabel temp = new JLabel();
      temp.setText(s);
      temp.setBorder(border1);
      rightPanel.add(temp);
  }

  void addBoxes() {
    int i = 0;

    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      JCheckBox tempBox = new JCheckBox("word " + i);
      boxes.add(tempBox);
      leftPanel.add(tempBox, gbc);
      //leftPanel.add(new JCheckBox("word" + i), gbc);
    }
  }
  private class BoxHandler implements ItemListener{
      public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {
            for (JCheckBox checkBox : boxes) {
                if (checkBox.isSelected() ) {
                    addText(checkBox.getText());
                }
            }
      }
  }

   void addBoxListeners() { // add listeners to all the boxes in the arraylist
      BoxHandler handler = new BoxHandler();
      int i = 0;
      for ( i = 0; i < boxes.size(); i++) {
          boxes.get(i).addItemListener(handler);
      }
  }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    CheckBox2 cb = new CheckBox2();
    cb.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    cb.pack();
    cb.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    cb.addBoxListeners();

    cb.setVisible(true);
  }
```

Below is part of my class declaration:

```
public class CheckBox2 extends JFrame {

  private ArrayList<JCheckBox> boxes = new ArrayList<JCheckBox>();
  JSplitPane splitPane;
  EmptyBorder border1 = new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5);
  private JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel();
  private JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel();
    JLabel labelOne = new JLabel();
    JLabel labelTwo = new JLabel();
...
```

Comment: You have not shown the code that adds the listeners. But why have a method called addBoxListeners() at all? Why not just add the listener inside the loop where you create each check box?

Comment: I added it, and you are right. That makes a lot more sense.